# Applescript going to bottom of page/middle of page after I press Command-S

Tags: applescript

Every time I press Command-S to save my script (which i will want to do after typing every new line, usually), Applescript automatically sets my cursor at the bottom of the page (or for some weird reason, the middle of the page, occasionally) so that I cannot continue typing the next line without having to scroll up and clicking in the appropriate place. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the script, it is automatically compiled. if the compilation found issue, then the script is saved, but editor set the cursor where the issue is...usually with a message.
If no error, then cursor stay where it was before the cmd S. that's the standard behavior
do you have error message after you comma S ?